# Are 32-bit software builds typically 64-bit optimized?

Tags: windows, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

EDIT: Just found out (thanks Ben Voigt for quickly pointing it out) that the proposition wasn't even possible.  For posterity here's the basic question, less my prior misconception about AMD's extensions:

I had been wondering whether it was common for 32-bit builds of (particularly Windows) software to detect the presence of a 64-bit processor and utilize 64-bit operands and the larger register file if one was present.  This was assuming that it was actually possible for a 32-bit process to utilize 64-bit instructions in much the same way as it was possible for 16-bit processes on i386 to utilize 32-bit instructions when such a CPU was physically present, via encoding override prefixes.  However, this is not possible as pointed out in the answers below.

Why would you want to use 64-bit instructions but 32-bit addressing?

Well, let's say that you know the dataset you are working on is small enough to fit in that address space.  For instance, you've used the 64-bit version of the program and, for what you're using it for, performance monitoring tells you the process is using 2GB or less.  (Actually, according to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/aa366778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#memory_limits), a 32-bit process with the IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE flag set will get 4GB user-space in 64-bit Windows.)

Some would figure it doesn't matter, but actually, it might.  In the 64-bit build, if I am not mistaken, *every single pointer the program stores will consume twice the physical RAM it needs to!*  If the program uses a lot of pointers (for instance, due to linked lists or hash tables), this could add up and reduce cache efficiency, etc.

Unfortunately as pointed out in Ben Voigt's answer below it is not possible at all in Windows, while a mode dedicated to this purpose has been done in Linux.

Comment: The whole point of 32 bit build is to enable it to run on a 32 bit machine. On a 32b machine you can address 4GB RAM, much less than what's available on the market right now, even for laptops 4GB isn't much any more. So your pointer example is completely pointless (pun intended)

Comment: why was this downvoted with no comments as to why?  I could be wrong too, but I feel like this was a well stated question, even if the OP was wrong in his thinking it is a valid question is it not?

Comment: @Sten Yes, RAM is cheap, but if a process uses tons of 64-bit pointers where 32-bit pointers would do, this is nevertheless inefficient and could impact performance by increasing cache misses.  This could be significant to computationally intensive processes such as ray tracers, where CPU cache size is still a material limitation.  (@adam thank you!)

Comment: @Kevin if the code was that critical why not write it in assembly and compile 64bit - this way you can have an 8 bit pointer if you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In fact, whether a program is a 32- or 64-bit image strictly speaking only determines its addressing mode, not what CPU features it uses, including data word size (barring API/library calls that expect a given size.)

No, this is incorrect.  In Windows, 32-bit vs 64-bit is synonymous with the two supported Intel architectures and instruction sets.  (Yes, there are other architectures supported -- Alpha, Itanium, ARM -- but these are always explicitly stated.)

A binary such as you describe would be "x86_64 architecture, tiny memory model" (commonly called `x32` for short), where tiny memory model means that pointers are smaller than the system word size, and data and code share the same address space.  [People have made Linux systems like this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI).

It is totally incompatible with "32-bit" x86 code.  x86 instructions don't even have encodings for the additional registers.  The mode bits of the CPU have to be set differently to support x86_64 instructions.  It's really similar to the concept of "based-addressing" and relative pointers which existed back in the days of 16-bit memory models.

x32 code uses x86_64 instructions, and uses the instructions for dealing with 32-bit data for accessing and performing computations with pointers.  This is made possible by virtual memory logic that restricts virtual addresses to the range (-2GB:+2GB), so that the normal sign extension associated with loading 32-bit variables into 64-bit registers creates valid 64-bit pointers.

When the CPU is in "long mode" in order to support instructions accessing the extra registers, it can't decode x86 instructions correctly.  For example, 0100 0000 is an ADD instruction in x86, but MOV in x86_64.

In summary, it is possible for 64-bit code to use 32-bit pointers, with some help from the allocator.  It is not possible to mix use of the additional registers into 32-bit code.

Comment: Ok, back with the i386, in a 16-bit TSS, operands were automatically 8 or 16 bits, or 8 or 32 bits in a 32-bit TSS - *but*, you could affix a prefix to an instruction that would switch the encoding to go between 8 or 32-bit operands instead.  If I understand you correctly, the x86-64 architecture doesn't have any equivalent way of overriding the operand size implied by the process' mode - correct?

Comment: @Kevin: x86_64 has instructions for many different operand sizes.  But you can't just mix x86_64-encoded instructions into x86 code, you need the processor placed into long mode.

Comment: Just dug up the AMD64 Architecture Programmer’s Manual and I see what you're talking about now.  The prefixes don't work for 64-bit operands even in compatibility mode in long mode.  Learn something every day!  Thanks for the quick response, I appreciate the clarification.

Comment: `0100 0000` is a REX prefix in x86_64, not any instructions. The prefix is encoded as `0100WRXB`. In x86 it's `inc` or `dec`, not `add` either

Answer (score 2):

In order to use x64 features you need to be running in 64 bit mode. You cannot use the 64 bit registers from a 32 bit process. A 32 bit process is restricted to 32 bit x86 opcodes. You cannot use any of the x64 features from a 32 bit process.

Comment: Partly right, partly wrong.  x64 instructions are usable only in "long mode".  But [it is completely possible to store and use 32-bit pointer variables in long mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI).  Windows hasn't chosen to support this, however.

Comment: @ben yes, sloppy on my part, thanks